# What Alice and Bob receive after entangled pair of qubits (generated by any source)?

Tags: entanglement

I'm bit confused regarding the "Alice and Bob receive one qubit each from an entangled pair of qubits". For example, Alice has 2 qubits = |0⟩, |1⟩, and Bob has 2 qubits = |0⟩, |1⟩, After superposition>>entangled pair generated, i.e.,  a qubit pair = 1/sqrt (2) [|00⟩ and |11⟩] is formed. What Alice and bob receive at their ends after entanglement? will appreciate to share diagram of qubits received at both ends.

If Alice and Bob receive one qubit each from an entangled pair of qubit. How come it is known or measured? as it is stated that measurement collapse the qubits states.

Comment: have a look at  https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49/tutorial-how-to-use-tex-mathjax-to-render-math-notation for math formatting on the site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initial source creates entangled qubits, e.g., in this description here:

$$\vert \Psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\vert 00\rangle + \vert 11\rangle)$$

I think the confusion arises from the fact that the above state is the state for two qubits; Alice and Bob each receive one of the physical qubits that, overall, must be described by the state above.

The subtlety then is the difference between a physical implementation of entangled pair of qubits, and a qubit itself, with respect to their information theoretic representation.

An entangled state of the form above might be describing the state of a pair of photons. These are two photons, then one is sent to Alice and another is sent to Bob. The overall description of the state must be the one from above; but Alice and Bob will only be able to act on the photonic modes that they receive. Let us use labels to describe the situation better:

$$\vert \Psi \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle_A\vert 0 \rangle_B + \vert 1\rangle_A \vert 1 \rangle_B)$$

These labels are to represent the idea that the two parties have each one the corresponding qubit, but the state must be characterized by this overall entangled state. Alice then might act on her part of the qubit, and Bob equivalently, meaning that they can operate with $U_A \otimes \mathbb{1}$ (for Alice) and $\mathbb{1} \otimes U_B$ (for Bob).

Physically, in the example I gave, this amounts for instance for the photon that Alice has passing through beam-splitters or phase-shifters on her side and Bob doing similar things on his side of the laboratory.

Important to note is that the entangled state representing the two photons is created and later shared, in this set up, and it is absolutely different than statistically representing mixtures of $|00>$ or $|11>$.

Finally, to discuss about measurement. Indeed, measurements collapse the wave function, and the state would not be entangled anymore. In the case above, measuring over $\{\vert 0\rangle \langle 0 \vert, \vert1\rangle\langle 1 \vert\}$, the state would collapse into either $|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$ depending on the outcomes each party gets. I hope this helped clarified a bit, but it will take some more examples and reflection to understand entanglement more deeply.

Answer (score 1):

Usually Alice and Bob receive one qubit each from a source of entanglement that prepares the Bell states (e.g., $(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$). The source may be either local to one of the parties, or located somewhere between them. Alice and Bob must have one storage qubit each (no matter their initial state), for storing the incoming quantum state.

The entangled state remains entangled even if the two qubits are in separated locations. When Alice or Bob measure their qubit, the entangled state collapses and the two qubits are no more correlated (e.g., they will be $|00\rangle$ or $|11\rangle$, with equal probability). If Alice measures $0$, she knows that Bob will measure (or has already measured) $0$ as well. Only after measuring, one party knows the other party's outcome.

Comment: Thank Michele for your reply. Apologize just to clarify. If Alice and Bob receive one qubit each that are entangled in the state (|00⟩+|11⟩)/√2, then the state of the qubit that Alice receives will be either |0⟩ or |1⟩ with equal probability? OR |00⟩ qubit state goes to Alice and |11⟩ qubit state goes to Bob? Specifically, not sure "which state of the qubit" that Bob receives will be correlated with the state of Alice's qubit?

Comment: No, Alice will receive a state that is $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ with equal probability, but cannot be written as $(|0\rangle + |1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$. Until measurement, you  still have to consider the state $(|0_A0_B\rangle + |1_A1_B\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$ as a whole even if the qubits are located in different places. The subscripts $_A, _B$ helps visualising the qubit owners.

Comment: Neither Alice's or Bob's qubit has (pure) state. If 2 qubits are entagled, only the system of two qubits have (pure) state, the individual qubits have not. You can say that individual qubits are in mixed states described by density  matrices.